# Can't upload files bigger than 8MB

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to make a file upload script and I've been struggling with this problem for a while.

I've read and tried all the SO answers related to this, but to no avail.

Here is what I tried in php. ini:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
memory_limit = 100M
```

In Apache I have:

```
<Directory /var/www/uploads>
php_value upload_max_filesize 10G
php_value post_max_size 10G
</Directory>
```

I might have tried something else that doesn't come to mind right now.

I also want to mention that everything under 8MB is uploaded without a problem. Also timeout isn't a problem either as the upload fails in just a few seconds.

P.S. I'm using Cloudflare. Could it be that this is what's blocking my upload?

Comment: Have you confirmed your location of PHP.ini by creating a test.php file with phpinfo() in it?

Comment: what does `print_r($_FILES)` show on a fail? is this a hosted account ?

Comment: I have just read about this somewhere else and I can confirm that I was editing a wrong php.ini. Now I'm getting this error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413 (Request Entity Too Large)`

Comment: "Depending on the plan your domain is subscribed to, CloudFlare limits data uploads to the following sizes:

100MB Free
100MB Pro
200MB Business
500MB Enterprise"

Comment: Then this isn't the problem, as I'm  getting the error when trying to upload a 35MB file. a 24MB file works now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm your location of PHP.ini by creating a test.php file with phpinfo() in it.

Next, check your Apache (LimitRequestBody directive*) and php.ini (upload_max_filesize) limits, so normally those are set higher. Value is in bytes.

Apache 2.0 has a default upload size of 524288,found in the php "include file" /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf, to override this value, place the following directive in your httpd.conf virtual host directive:

```
<Files *.php>
LimitRequestBody 30000000
</Files>
```

(This example limits request body to 30M)

Apache 1.3 does not have this default, and so you normally have to change only the php.ini (upload_max_filesize,post_max_size) values and the config.ini (maxuploadfilesize) value.

Finally, check RequestReadTimeout setting. More at https://serverfault.com/a/260389

Comment: I was indeed editing a wrong php.ini, but I've found the right one. I have also added that in my conf. Now I get the following error: `413 Request Entity Too Large.
The requested resource/upload.php
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in
the request exceeds the capacity limit.`

I'm using Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5.

I managed to upload a 24MB file, but with a 35MB one I get that error.

Comment: See my note: check RequestReadTimeout setting. More at http://serverfault.com/a/260389

Comment: The LimitRequestBody was the answer, only that your code was limiting it to ~30MB and I copied it directly. Now I've added two more zeroes and it's great. Thanks!

Comment: Added note about the 30M. Glad you got it.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes excute time occur problem,
use set_time_limit(0);

or

Check the php.ini
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //0