# PHP ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error with FILE UPLOAD more than 8MBs

Tags: php, file, google-chrome, file-upload, upload

My server settings are as below:

- **max_execution_time :** 0
- **max_input_time :** -1
- **memory_limit :** 128M
- **upload_max_filesize :** 128M
- **post_max_size :** 128M

still I am getting **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** while uploading a file (size > 8MBs). Not even `var_dump($_FILES);` is working. Any file size below 8MBs is uploading easily. Not sure where I am wrong. Please suggest.

Although all the server configurations are set still I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't upload files bigger than 8MB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058742/cant-upload-files-bigger-than-8mb)

Comment: What web server are you using? For Apache 2.0, check out @S.I.'s comment, for NGINX, you might need to edit the `client_max_body_size` in your `nginx.conf`.

Comment: Where can I edit this? I have cpanel detail and ftp detail. This is a shared hosting.

Comment: Server Apache is 2.4.23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case is the file I was trying to upload. 
That PDF file was corrupted. I repaired the PDF file with some online PDF file repairing tool and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Check your php settings for both of these:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

Comment: upload_max_filesize is 128M and post_max_size : 128M

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have shared server, you can add php.ini file and add following lines to it.

> memory_limit = 1024M
>   max_input_vars = 2000
>   upload_max_filesize = 300M
>   post_max_size = 300M
>   max_execution_time = 990

This will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In additional to the above, make sure that

LimitRequestBody

in your .htaccess file is set properly or disabled altogether. 0 means unlimited

Docs here

[Apache LimitRequestBody Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)