# can't upload large file -> Error 413 or ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php

I have a problem with my webserver. I'm currently migrating my webserver from another server and I have an error which doesn't  appear with Nextcloud. In fact, I can't upload big file on a website because sometimes when I upload a file it says :"ERR_CONNECTIO_RESET" and it cancel the upload. Or, if it succeded upload my file, the script return ERROR 413.
So I've copy the entire php.ini of my previous server, I have this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 25600M
post_max_size = 25600M
memory_limit = 2048M
```

and some other paramaters which normaly permit big files upload.

I don't know what's going wrong, thanks in advance!
PS:Sorry for my bad english :(
PS2:After googling, this is probably because of my ssl cert.

Comment: is it a wordpress site ?

Comment: No it is a private video hosting site like playtube

Comment: is the server owned (and 100% managed) by you or you rent the service from a hosting company ?

Comment: It's a home server which is under my stairs xD

Comment: please check your network configuration and see whether your network equipment has problem(s).

Comment: I don't think that there is a link with the problem. I think it's because the script probably don't care about one of the parameters. Strange...

Comment: at least reboot your switch and router once - it doesn't hurt (and sometimes can fix the problem). After that you may try to upload the large file by FTP to see whether it works or not. (if FTP also fails, then it is not just the PHP.ini problem)

Comment: I've done this, nothing change. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you had already increased the limit of all parameters then make sure to check that all of them are affecting or not?. You can test it by checking your server's phpinfo.

Comment: <Files *.php>
LimitRequestBody 30000000
</Files>

possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058742/cant-upload-files-bigger-than-8mb

Answer (score 0):

It was because of Cloudflare's proxy. I disabled it and it work. I will see how to make it work with CF. :(